# Oauth token expires while downloading code from GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth

I followed this instructions to download my source code from an especific deployed version:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code

My application has 9972 files. I can start the download process, but it always stops in 60%. The problem is that the Oauth token expires.

```
60% [6058/9972] WEB-INF/classes/com/neo/sifec/client/retencionesSAT/WinRetencionesSAT$4.class
60% [6059/9972] WEB-INF/classes/com/neo/sifec/client/catalogos/produccion/CpsMaquileros$2.class
60% [6060/9972] WEB-INF/classes/com/neo/sifec/client/contabilidad/WinRep_RentabilidadXCC$6.class
60% [6061/9972] WEB-INF/classes/com/neo/sifec/client/contabilidad/WinCierreEjercicio$1.class
60% [6062/9972] WEB-INF/classes/com/neo/sifec/client/facturacion/CpsContrato.class
60% [6063/9972] WEB-INF/classes/com/neo/sifec/client/facturacion/CpsContrato$36.class

jul 04, 2017 2:41:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/files/get?id=6062&app_id=factura****&version=p.402325307993766787&
401 Unauthorized
Invalid OAuth token
This is try #0

Error Details:
Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/files/get?id=6062&app_id=facturanube&version=p.402325307993766787&
401 Unauthorized
Invalid OAuth token


Unable to download file WEB-INF/classes/com/neo/sifec/client/facturacion/CpsContrato$36.class
```

I looked out in the appcfg.cmd command help and I didn't find anything that could help me.

This is the command I am using:

```
appcfg.cmd -A factura*** -V p -a --passin -n 5 download_app c:\here
```

Any help is well received!

*AppEngineSDK version: 1.9.42*